# Php: count values from a text file

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script to store IP adresses in a text file and than to count unique IP. For example if i have 3 different IP in the txt file

```
111.111.111.111
111.111.111.111
111.111.111.111
222.222.222.222
222.222.222.222
000.000.000.000
000.000.000.000
000.000.000.000
000.000.000.000
000.000.000.000
```

Than this is the result that i'm trying to have

```
111.111.111.111 = 3 (var = $total_visits)
222.222.222.222 = 2 (var = $total_visits)
000.000.000.000 = 5 (var = $total_visits)
```

I know that would be more realistic to built a database, but this function is for a special page that has a small number of users, let say 20-30 unique visitor per week.

My final goal is to warning the users like that:

```
$x = 5; // total visits of a unique IP;
if ($x > 6)
{
header('Location: http://example.com/banned.php');
}
elseif ($x > 5)
{
echo 'First Warn! Go away!';
}
```

Comment: What code have you developed so far? This is not a programming service.

Comment: Why does it matter what my answer is? Your arrogance take it for yourself

Comment: how much big the file is? how many lines? hint: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: It doesnt work getting from the text file. 

This is what i did:
    $log = 'log.txt';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $file = file_get_contents($log);
    $fp = fopen($log, 'a+');
    fwrite($fp, '"' . $ip. '", ' . "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
    echo $file . '<br>';
    $lines = count(file($log));

Comment: the problem is that the code is counting the lines. Im trying to count the unique ip, not all IPs

Comment: You should update your question with that code, it will be easier to read there. See @gengisdave's comment, that function should count the unique values for you.

Comment: Hint2 : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php BUT only if file will not have too many lines!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
print_r(array_count_values(explode("\r\n", $file)));
```

since $file is the data you read from the file. As long as the file is small enough.

Comment: Finally, thank you. 

Ps: I came here to learn, not to teach. Nobody is born learned

Comment: Of course not, but I could not have answered that as short and easy without you posting your file-code. No offense or arrogance meant. ;)

Comment: Well, as i said the code in the post was for the FINAL GOAL. But i said also that the result that i'm trying to have is to group unique ip in one value. Maybe i wasnt clearly, but your code did the job. ;)